# How can i decrease the size of the cell in a table?

Tags: tables

I am drawing a long table with a single column. I have drawn the table but the cell size is too big. How can i reduce the cell size? And i wanted to keep the line continuing on next page on the right corner of the page instead of the left corner. How can i do it. My code is as follows. I have attached an image of the error.
[image]

```
\begingroup
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
 \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ |l||*{1}{>{\hskip 1em}X|} }
%\begin{xltabular}{ |p{3 cm}||p{3.8cm}| }
\caption{Simulation data of overall system}
\label{tab:overalldata}\\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\makecell[t]{System parameters}
    &   \mcx{Simulation data}\\
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
\endfirsthead
%\caption[]{Data comparison of steady state and transient simulation}    \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\makecell{System parameters}
    &   \mcx{Simulation data}\\
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
\endhead
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\small\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \Xhline{1pt}
\endlastfoot
Pel\_Boiler (\si{KW})    &92.572\\ 
N\_STEAM\_RECY (\si{mol/s}) &1.686\\
Pel\_SH (\si{KW})   &66.869 \\ 
T\_AC\_OUT (\si{K}) &945.732\\
T\_CC\_OUT (\si{K}) &885.8513695\\
\hline
\end{xltabular}
\endgroup
```

Comment: As far as I can see, your table has two columns :-). For smaller columnswidth you should make table narrower, i.e. instead of `xltabular` use `longtable`

Comment: Hard to guess, because the code shows only a part. In fact I see 2 columns. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Also please extend your code fragment to complete self contained document, which we can test as it is. In your code fragment are some new commands, which definition is unknown to us.

Comment: Using \multicolumn{4} inside of a table that has just 2 columns will result in an error message. Please make sure, your code compiles without error messages before taking a look at the pdf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

In above table are used `longtable` and `siunitx` packages. `xparse` is used for definition of new commands using instead of `\multicolumn{...}{...}{<content>}`. Showed result need (at least) four compilation of the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{cellspace, longtable}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{|Cc|}m}
    {\multicolumn{2}{#1}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcl{O{c}m}
    {\multicolumn{1}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}            
    \begin{longtable}{| Cr s[table-unit-alignment = left] 
                      |    S[zero-decimal-to-integer,
                             round-mode=places,
                             round-precision=3]
                      |}
\caption{Simulation data of overall system.}
\label{tab:s:align}                                     \\
    \hline
\mcc{System parameters}             & {value}           \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Simulation data of overall system.}    \\
    \hline
\mcc{System parameters}             & {value}           \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
\mcl{}          & \mcc[r]{\footnotesize{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
% table body
Pel\_Boiler     & \kilo\watt        &   92.572      \\
N\_STEAM\_RECY  & \mol\per\second   &    1.686      \\
Pel\_SH         & \kilo\watt        &   66.869      \\
T\_AC\_OUT      & \kelvin           &  945.732      \\
T\_CC\_OUT      & \kelvin           &  885.8513695  \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Due to incompatibility between `makegapedcells` macro defined in `makecell` with formatting `s` and `S` columns in aditem MWE the `makecell` package is replaced by `cellspace` for adding vertical space into cells.

Now is also added rounding option to `S` column.

Comment: @VISHNU, see edited answer.